# Versioning objects in firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, rest

I am using firebase as a database for a mobile application. Mobile application version 1 using a certain DB structure. But in version 2 I have a major schema changes. I could not find any specific documentation which would mention the best practices for managing DB upgrades. So I am thinking of following steps, which looks good on paper.

1. Application version 1 is in production using *firebase/v1*
2. Copy version 1 schema *firebase/v1* to *firebase/v2*
3. Upgrade *firebase/v2* schema
4. Disable write operations on *firebase/v1*
5. Distribute application v2 pointing to *firebase/v2*

With these steps users with older versions app would be able to only read the data. So unless they dont upgrade the app they wont be able to modify any data.

Do I going in the right direction in managing my schema updates? Or is there any better way to do this.

Comment: I would always first look for backwards compatible approach, since that is the least disruptive to your users. If you cannot find a backwards compatible approach, what you propose is indeed a common second. In cases like this it helps if you've put an "your app is in read-only mode because it is outdated. Please upgrade by clicking..." in your app already.

Comment: Thanks Frank for clearing my doubts, I was waiting for this. In this particular case we won't be able to make schema changes backward compatible. Thats what why was trying to do something different, which I was not sure about being the best possible solution.

Comment: I agree with @FrankvanPuffelen always the backward compatibility should be the first priority. 

But @kunal if you can't find a way there is another solution, which almost the same with yours.

You could easily write a Firebase cloud function which always populates the `firebase/v2` without blocking the writes for `firebase/v1`. So when the users will update the app to newest version will be able to smoothly migrated to new firebase data structure without an issue.

We have done this couple of times in our cases and at ezhome we are using firebase for many years now.

Comment: I recommend you to actually force users to upgrade in order to use the app instead of backward compatibility. Otherwise it might be really hard for you to maintain your app. Unfortunately, working with Firebase DB becomes problematic when your data increases so make sure that in your second version you have a better structure than the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Use cloud function database functions to migrate data from db/v1 to db/v2. On update event in db/v1, you can write to db/v2 in parallel, so all active user data can move into db/v2.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Migrate data asap!