# Firebase(Android), add key in the table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating the chat app, and wondering to know what the best way to handle situation when will be added key to a node in the `json` table, and pre versions of the application with old `Class` represents the node(with less variables) will be crashed.

For example:

```
mChatUser = childDataSnapshot.getValue(ChatUser.class);
```

In table ChatUser node have 4 String keys, as well as, `ChatUser.class` has 4 String variables, it is ok. But after we update `ChatUser` nodes to have 5 variables and `ChatUser.class` to have 5 variables, but app still not updated to all devices, so in old versions will be crash. How to avoid it? And best way to add keys?
Thanks.

Comment: migrate old `ChatUser`s to the new `ChatUser` model.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294158/versioning-objects-in-firebase and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168665/is-there-a-way-to-version-objects-in-firebase-that-are-meant-to-be-read-only and https://calendee.com/2015/05/17/api-versioning-trick-for-firebase/

Comment: Thanks! Seems best way to handle DB Schema changes is to disallow use app until app is updated. What do you think about it?